# Splitting text from text file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, split

i have a content in my text file, like below

[image]

now i want to split all the content which have ":" in that like Mode-->Allowed, Status --> Started etc BSSID is to exempted from this.

can anyone help me about how i would be going through to split content, i tried splitting content based on ":" but i gets Hosted network settings -------------- and hosted network status ---------- also in the splits.

Comment: There must be like a couple thousand identical questions around SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with @lc.'s answer but if you need something with more custom logic, try this:

```
var keyValue = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var lineItem in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Kane\Desktop\yourFile.txt").Where(x => x.Contains(": ")))
{
    var splitPosition = lineItem.IndexOf(": ", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    var key = lineItem.Substring(0, splitPosition);
    var value = lineItem.Substring(splitPosition + 1);

    // add in functions for checking null
    // add in functions for trimming
    // add in special cases for 
    keyValue.Add(key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your file, I would read line by line, splitting on ": " (the space is the easy way to not split your IPv6 addresses). Then only accept lines that contain the string. Something like:

```
from line in textFileLines.Where(x=>x.Contains(": "))
select x.Split(": ")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the fixed lenth columns which you have like (x, y) then i think this is more suitable way to read text files

```
   public DataTable GetDataTableFromTextFile(string filepath) 
    {
                                string line;
                                DataTable dt = new DataTable();                         
                                using (TextReader tr = File.OpenText(filepath))
                                {
                                    while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
                                    {
                                        string[] items = line.Split('\t',":",";","=");
                                        if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
                                        {
                                            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FirstColumn", typeof(string)));
                                            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SecondColumn", typeof(string)));
                                            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ThridColumn", typeof(string)));

                                        }

                                        if (items.Length > 0 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(items[0].ToString()))
                                        {
                                            dt.Rows.Add(items);                                       
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
    return dt;

}
```

hope fully this will be helpful to you.

you can add columns as much as you want. and the dt.rows.add(item) will add only columns in the row as it has e.g item has only two items then the row will be added with two columns only.